# SailsJS and Forever doesn't work with CoffeeScript

Tags: node.js, sails.js, forever

I have a SailsJS app, with much of it written in CoffeeScript.
When running it in Prod mode using "sails lift" all is good.

Running it with forever doesn't work. If I examine the logs, the problem seems to be with node running app.js

> /var/www/obelix/api/models/Catalogue.coffee:2
>     attributes:
>               ^
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
>      at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
>      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>      at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>      at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>      at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>      at require (module.js:380:17)
>      at /var/www/obelix/node_modules/sails/node_modules/include-all/index.js:96:53
>      at Array.forEach (native)
>      at requireAll (/var/www/obelix/node_modules/sails/node_modules/include->all/index.js:40:9)
>      at buildDictionary >(/var/www/obelix/node_modules/sails/lib/moduleloader/index.js:60:36)

Is it possible to get a sails+coffeescript app to run using node/forever?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that coffee-script support doesn't work unless you're using `sails lift`.
Try requiring coffee-script in your app.js file:

```
// Start sails and pass it command line arguments
require('coffee-script');
require('sails').lift(require('optimist').argv);
```

Then `npm install coffee-script --save`